# SSRS connection to an existing instance

Tags: reporting-services

I have a `SQL 2012` instance called `LTT` which contains a database called `ReportServer$LTT`. I have installed `SSRS 2017`. After the installation of `SSRS2017` it is using `SSRS` as its Report Server Instance. But I need it to use `LTT`. How do i change the Report Server Instance? Using SQL Management Studio I am unable to connect to `<servername>\LTT` Report Server and I get the following error:

> The Reporting Services instance could not be found.
>   (MS.sqlserver.managment.UI.RSClient)

I am also unable to connect to: \SSRS and get this error:

> Unable to connect to the server at \SSRS. The specified
>   URL might not be valid or there might be a problem with the report
>   server version of configuration. Specify a different URL....

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to remote desktop to the report server. Then open **Reporting Services Configuration Manager**.

Click on the "Database" tab. From there you'll be able to change the database the report manager uses.

[image: screenshot]